# Symfony validation of decimal range plus extra number

Tags: symfony, validation

I am trying to validate a **decimal** range between 8 and 39, or 99:

My entity Data.php looks like this:

```
/**
* @var decimal
* @Assert\Expression(
*     "this.getFu5Weight() in 8..39 or this.getFu5Weight() == 99",
*     message="3. Weight at assessment: this value has to be between 8 and 39, or 99 if unknown"
* )
*/
private $fu5Weight;
```

In Form DataType.php:

```
    ->add('fu5Weight', 'number', array('invalid_message'=>'3. Weight at assessment: this value has to be between 8 and 39, or 99 if unknown'))
```

In Data.orm.yml:

```
fu5Weight:
    type: decimal
    nullable: true
    precision: 18
    scale: 2
    column: FU5_Weight
```

The range functions well and it turns errors when outside the range. The problem is that it also turns erros when decimal numbers are entered.

Any idea?

I tried:

```
@Assert\Expression(
    *     "this.getFu5Weight() in 8.00..39.00 or this.getFu5Weight() == 99"
```

Obviously, it did not work.
The provided min and max of Symfony apperently does not allow to have an extra number outside of the range. I would be happy with a simple solution without Regex.

Thank you for the support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`in 8..39` creates this array : `[8,9,10,...,39]` and checks if your value is in this array. Obviously, you can't create an array with all float values between 8 and 39.

Try this instead :

```
/**
* @var decimal
* @Assert\Expression(
*     "(this.getFu5Weight() >= 8 and this.getFu5Weight() <= 39) or this.getFu5Weight() == 99",
*     message="3. Weight at assessment: this value has to be between 8 and 39, or 99 if unknown"
* )
*/
```